# c++ Singleton with map cause "violation reading location"

Tags: c++, singleton

I was trying to create a singleton to access a global-like class. This class work perfectly except when I use the `std::map` inside.

(yes i know, putting methods in .h..., but it's for debugging):

panthera.h

```
class Panthera
{
private:
    std::map<std::string, std::map<long, Object *>> entities;

public:
    Panthera(void);
    ~Panthera(void);

    static Panthera * GetInstance()
    {
    static Panthera *engine_ = new Panthera();
    return engine_;
    }

    void Run() {std::cout << "I run" << std::endl;}
    void DOESNOTWORK(Object *o) {this->entities["test"][0] = o;}
};
```

main.cpp

```
Panthera::GetInstance()->Run(); // no problem
Panthera::GetInstance()->DOESNOTWORK(); // access violation
```

Been trying to solve this for some time now... Any leads?

---

---

After looking into things with OneonOne i understood that the problem was the class Object (it work if I replace it by anempty class)

tried to look in this class for incoherency/other but can't find the root of the problem, so here is the class

Object.h

```
#pragma once

#include "Vector2.h"
#include <list>

class Object
{
protected:
    Vector2 location;
    float rotation;
    std::string plane;
    unsigned long id;

    std::list<Object *> children;

public:
    Object(void);
    Object(Vector2 const & location, std::string const & plane = "background", float rotation = 0);
    Object(Object const & other);

    ~Object(void);

public:
    virtual void SetLocation(Vector2 const & location);
    virtual Vector2 GetLocation() const;

    virtual void SetRotation(float);
    virtual float GetRotation() const;

    virtual void Move(Vector2 const & displacement);
    virtual void Rotate(float angle);

    virtual void Adopt(Object * other, Vector2 const & mountPoint = Vector2());
    virtual Vector2 Mount(Vector2 const & other) const;

    std::string GetPlane() const;
    long GetId() const;
};
```

the implementation is trivial, and the class in itself run fine EXCEPT when it is added in a `std::map` and this only from a singleton...

As usual, thank you in advance for any help (and ask if you need the source file (or the Vector2 class))

---

---

As requested, the Object.cpp file

```
#include "Object.h"
#include "Matrix.h"
#include "Panthera.h"

Object::Object(void): location(Vector2()), rotation(0), plane("background")
{
    this->id = reinterpret_cast<long>(this);
    Panthera::GetInstance()->DOESNOTWORK(this);
}

Object::Object(Vector2 const & location, std::string const & plane, float rotation): location(location), rotation(rotation), plane(plane)
{
    this->id = reinterpret_cast<long>(this);
    //Panthera::GetInstance().Add(this);
}

Object::Object(Object const & other)
{
    *this = other;
    this->id = reinterpret_cast<long>(this);
    // Panthera::GetInstance().Add(this);
}

Object::~Object(void)
{
}

void Object::SetLocation(Vector2 const & location)
{
    this->Move(location - this->location);
}

Vector2 Object::GetLocation() const
{
    return this->location;
}

void Object::SetRotation(float rotation)
{
    this->Rotate(rotation - this->rotation);
}

float Object::GetRotation() const
{
    return this->rotation;
}

void Object::Move(Vector2 const & displacement)
{
    std::list<Object *>::iterator it;

    for (it = this->children.begin() ; it != this->children.end(); ++it)
    {
        (*it)->Move(displacement);
    }
    this->location += displacement;
}

void Object::Rotate(float angle)
{
    std::list<Object *>::iterator it;

    for (it = this->children.begin() ; it != this->children.end(); ++it)
    {
        (*it)->SetLocation(Matrix::Transform((*it)->GetLocation() - this->location, angle) + this->location);
    }
    this->rotation += angle;
}

void Object::Adopt(Object * other, Vector2 const & mountpoint)
{
    other->SetLocation(this->Mount(Matrix::Transform(mountpoint, this->rotation)));

    this->children.push_back(other);
}

Vector2 Object::Mount(Vector2 const & other) const
{
    return Vector2(this->location + other);
}

std::string Object::GetPlane() const
{
    return this->plane;
}

long Object::GetId() const
{
    return this->id;
}
```

---

---

Update: just calling the constructor of Object fails. for some reason it doesn't let me use the singleton in his constructor, => this is the root of the problem

---

**Resolved**: the problem was having a Object in the singleton class, the Object constructor made use of the singleton before it was initialized.

Comment: Show the actual code for the `Object` constructor(s) because the answer is almost certainly there.

Comment: Hum, the fect that i use "Panthera::GetInstance()->Add(this);" in the constructor might be the source of the problem, good guess

Comment: -Ha but if the object is created before, it still does the same error.

Comment: Played with it a bit, still can't get what the problem is though

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't even compile because your Constructor and Destruct weren't implemented.

Here's a C++11 version :

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
class Object {};

class Panthera {
private:
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unordered_map<long, Object *>> entities;
    Panthera() noexcept {}

public:

    static Panthera & GetInstance() noexcept {
        static Panthera engine_;
        return engine_;
    }

    void Run() {std::cout << "I run" << std::endl;}
    void worksnow() {this->entities["test"][0] = new Object;}
    void get_test() {
        std::cout << this->entities["test"].size() << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Panthera::GetInstance().Run(); // no problem
    Panthera::GetInstance().worksnow(); //works too
    Panthera::GetInstance().get_test();
    return 0;
}
```

Test :

```
|---> clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -lc++abi -I. test-singleton.cpp  && ./a.out 
I run
1
```

The original code works fine for me, so your problem is compiler related or with the omitted code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
class Object {};

class Panthera {
    private:
        std::map<std::string, std::map<long, Object *> > entities;
    public:
        Panthera(void) {}
        ~Panthera(void) {}

    static Panthera * GetInstance() {
        static Panthera *engine_ = new Panthera();
        return engine_;
    }

    void Run() {std::cout << "I run" << std::endl;}
    void DOESNOTWORK() {
        this->entities["test"][0] = new Object;
        std::cout << this->entities["test"].size() << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {

    Panthera::GetInstance()->Run(); // no problem
    Panthera::GetInstance()->DOESNOTWORK(); // access violation
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I didn't implement the c and dc in this example because i just showed the points of interest, as i have told in the question the code run well as long as i do not use the map.

This aside, i have some question if you don't mind:
Why the unordered_map ?
What is "Panthera() noexcept {}" ?

 Thank for your time

Comment: [noexcept](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept), unordered_map is generally faster (unless you need your keys ordered).

Comment: what about the noexcept?
Edit: after a look at it, it seem to be c++11. So it is not possible to run this on c99/other i guess?
Edit: nevermind, i found what is it for. It is not involved in the problem.

Comment: noexcept is more of an optimization, or you can just delete the constructor all together.

Comment: Re, you are right, i replaced "Object *" by an empty class "test *", everything works fine. Should i post this class ? (i'll see what i can find on object in the meantime)